# R Shiny App - NumericInput Arrows in Internet Explorer

Tags: r, shiny

HTML5's input type numeric's arrows (aka spinners) are not supported by Internet explorer. The result is that when using numericInput(), the user can only enter numbers manually. Does anyone know of a work around for this? I know that jQuery UI has an numeric input with arrows (http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) but I can't even fathom how this could be used instead of numericInput().

Thank you.